# Android: Check radio button by its position in the radio group

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group, android-radiogroup

I got the position of a radio in a radio group by using indexOfChild. How can I use this index to check the radio that has this particular index?

Comment: Can you post some of your code?  And I do not clearly understand your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
radioGroup.check(((RadioButton)radioGroup.getChildAt(index)).getId())
```

Comment: It's good if you don't have any other views inside your `radioGroup`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i in listCategory.indices){
    if ((categoryRadioGroup[i] as RadioButton).isChecked) {
        Toast.makeText(myContext, "$i", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```